# Using impedance on PCB design

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, impedance

I am trying to make PCB with W5500 (Ethernet module). I am not finding original supplies so I am looking for alternatives. I did research, and I couldn't find HH-1M1608-12 IJT. I looked at Sparkfun's designs and I found MH2029-300Y but when I read the data sheet they use different values.

[image]

[image]

Sparkfun uses the second photo. What I don't understand is how are they choosing right supplies. There is quite a difference. I know if they do that, there must be something. For example, I would choose this:

[image]

The L is using for here (right one Sparkfun's):

[image]

Is this L used for maximizing the power transfer, minimizing signal reflection from the load, or something that I don't know? Also, which L should I use (I don't have HH-1M1608-12 IJT)?

Comment: Thank your for edit @JRE

Comment: The power supply couples to the center tap of the Ethernet transformer, therefore there is coupling of high frequency signals into your power supply and vice versa ,  the **choke** is specified to suppress those transients through overwhelming losses and isolate the rest of your digital electronics. The choke is specified such that  at low frequencies it behaves as an inductor, at high frequency it looks like a large resistance.  Therefore it is to prevent the Ethernet physical layer  from presenting an issue.

Comment: Thank you for explain, which impedance should I use? Should I use MH2029-300Y (Sparkfun's.)

Comment: The only way to say for sure is to see your entire design,  If you can't share  then I would suggest building and testing several variants, then the trick is , what will you test for?

Comment: Why are you asking about the right supply without specs and then only discuss the SMT ferrite beads??   The Sparkfun W5500  typically uses < 150 mA but these schematics provide 2A or 3A  with beads for some other loads  See 5.4 https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Dev/Arduino/Shields/W5500_datasheet_v1.0.2_1.pdf   Do you understand the properties of different ferrite beads? Do you know how to specify current and common mode impedance  ?  Please state overall power specs and partial power for Ethernet IC then ask to understand what isolation you need before trying to design it.3A  vs 150 mA load

Comment: @crasic I am making [this](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/rp2040/hardware-design-with-rp2040.pdf) . I am not using impedance on this link because they didn't use. I will use impedance for wiznett5500. This is my first PCB design I am beginner.

Comment: Tony Stewart EE75, I am trying to implement ethernet to raspberry pi pico and I will use 150mA load , that is the right decision I guess. I don't know those thing , this is my first PCB design and I am beginner.

Comment: Pay attention to all rPi design info from board thickness for Zo track impedance with track width and low ESR cap size, choice and placement.    re-write question with power and ripple spec assumptions for Analog and digital  before you consider parts and doubts

Comment: Be clear if you are using any Analog functions.   That link says *"There is an AGND pin on Raspberry Pi Pico which is intended to be used  as  a  low  noise  ADC  return  path,  but  as  we  are  not  using  the  ADC  in  this  application,  we  simply  connect  this  to regular GND. There is also an ADC_VREF pin, which can be optionally used to supply a clean and stable reference as an alternative  to  the  Raspberry  Pi  Pico  onboard  3.3V  supply,  but  again,  as  we  are  not  using  the  ADC,  we  can  safely  leave this  pin  floating."*

Comment: Since ADC uses A3V3 and AGnd, the differential ripple there must be less than LSB of ADC

Comment: Thank you Tony Stewart EE75

Comment: [wiznett](https://cdn.sos.sk/productdata/43/24/8adad58a/wiz850io.pdf) in this link they used AVDD and AGND pins, so I need to use Raspberry pi pico's AGND and ADC_VREF I guess?